# how to save and get form state from localstorage in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i wanted to save form state in `localstorage`, i,e i'm able to save but

i'm **unable to** save the `input` typed `data`

**expected output:** suppose i type **doggy** inside input box then i want to retain that **doggy**, to be filled inside `cloned` one.

**here is codepen:**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGYdKO?editors=1010

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#getstate',function(){
      var cloned = $('#wrapper-rrr').clone();
      console.log('cloned.html()',cloned.html());
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
         localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(cloned.html()));
      }else{
        var lastForm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
         $('#displayAboveResult').html(lastForm);
      }
   });
})
```

```css
#displayAboveResult{
  margin-top:40px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper-rrr">
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="capture typed input into localstorage">
    <input type="checkbox" id="getstate">
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="displayAboveResult">
    <p>Empty in the begining</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Store the value from input. Why storing HTML?

Comment: Need to save whole state of the form in actual project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just touch all the inputs before making a clone for changing its DOM state.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#getstate',function(){
     $('input:text').each(function() {
         $(this).attr('value',           $(this).val());
     });
      var cloned = $('#wrapper-rrr').clone(true);
     console.log('cloned.html()',cloned.html());
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
         localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(cloned.html()));
      }else{
        var lastForm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
         $('#displayAboveResult').html(lastForm);
      }
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper-rrr">
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="capture typed input into localstorage" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="getstate" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="displayAboveResult">
    <p>Empty in the begining</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**Code pen example :** https://codepen.io/sumesh-tg/pen/wELGKO

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[My codePen example](https://codepen.io/urmajesty516/pen/GXaJJP)

let's give `<input type="text" placeholder="capture typed input into localstorage">` a id, say `#toBeRetain`.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#getstate',function(){

      var cloned = $('#wrapper-rrr').clone(); 
      //console.log('cloned.html()',cloned.html());
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
         localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(cloned.html()));
      }else{
         var lastForm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
         $('#displayAboveResult').html(lastForm);
         /*Set input value after clone*/
         $('#displayAboveResult #toBeRetain').val(localStorage['savedTxt']);
      }
  });
  /*Save input change to a localStorage variable*/
   $(document).on('change','#toBeRetain',function(){
      if(localStorage['savedTxt']){
         localStorage['savedTxt']=$('#toBeRetain').val();
      }else{
         localStorage.setItem("savedTxt",$('#toBeRetain').val());
      }           
  });
  //console.log(localStorage['savedTxt']);
})
```

When a user's typing in the input, it's dom property doesn't get updated at once, hence you can't clone its value.

Another point is, I'm not sure if you only need to copy the entire thing once or multiple times, if it's the latter scenario, you need to select the parent div using `$(this).parent()` and change selector `#` to `.`.

Comment: but i have 100 input , then i have to write 100 times this code

Comment: You don't have to. I wrote this code with the example you provided, it's the simplest case. The basic idea is to store the input value, and set the value to the cloned one, because you can't do this with clone html. If you have 100 input value, then store them in an array and iterate through the array to set the values